# In Google Sheets, how do I get the folder name where the current Spreadsheet is located and write it in a cell? (with AppScript possibly)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet in a folder in google Drive, let's call the folder "FolderX"

I opened AppScript in the Spreadsheet and wrote this function:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const ss_id = ss.getId();
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss_id);
  const parent_folders = file.getParents()
  const folder_name = parent_folders.next().getName(); //desired result
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(folder_name); 
}
```

(I got that function from [Get Folder Name in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119388/get-folder-name-in-google-apps-script))

I also enabled the appscript.json editability in the settings and added the lines to add the scopes I needed, in total it looks like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Rome",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

However when trying to run the function I get this error: "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)."
Did I miss something in the code? Is there a way to get the result I want, a custom function to get the value "FolderX" written in a cell of the Spreadsheet?

Additional information: I tried with triggers and it works, the name of the folder gets written on cell A1 every minute, however there is a problem when copying the Spreadsheet: the trigger does not get copied and the cell remains empty.

Basically I have 5 spreadsheets inside a folder, each spreadsheet needs to have the name of the folder in one of their cells, and I need to be able to duplicate the whole folder, give it another name, and the folder name be written inside the spreadsheets that are in that folder. I feel like it's possible but I don't know where to go from here.

Sorry for the long explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DriveApp.getFolderById results in "you do not have permission" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028119/driveapp-getfolderbyid-results-in-you-do-not-have-permission-error)

Answer (score 2):

The code is fine and should work when you are running it directly from the Apps Script.

It looks like you are using it as a custom function, in this case it won't work since you are using a service which requires user authorization.

[image]

This is an expected behavior stated in the [Custom Function Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced):
[image]

**Another Reference:** [No permission to call DriveApp](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/104201979/you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-driveapp-getfilesbyname?hl=en)

Custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. They can only call services that do not have access to personal data. The Drive Service has access to personal data, which is why it cannot be called from a custom function.

---

**[Installable Triggers:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)**

As for the trigger since it is an installable trigger so it does not get copied along when you copy the spreadsheet so you have to recreate/re-setup the trigger again on the copies.

**Suggestion:**

I don't recommend using the Installable trigger for this scenario if you don't need to run the script at specific time intervals.

What you can do is either create a [Custom Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) or a Button which will run the app script function you have.

**Using Custom Menu:**
[image]
I just tweaked the code a bit to set the value on the currently selected cell.

**Using Button:**

[image]

Comment: I upvoted because I didn't fully explained myself, I tried with Custom Menu and also with applying the script to a drawing/image. The problem I have with both is that I need to manually click them, they don't automatically write the value down if I duplicate the sheet, unless I open the spreadsheet and click on them. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @Dravis800 how about creating a standalone apps script (not bound to sheet) which calls all the spreadsheet by their URL -> get their folder name -> set value to a selected range? You just have to run the script once from the script editor and it will be applied to all the spreadsheets.

Comment: That sounds promising! Could you point me to a guide on how to make this (or explain me if it's short)? t I'm extremely new to App Scripts

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFolder() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//Logger outputs the name of this spreadsheet folder
  const id = ss.getId();
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  const f = file.getParents().next()
  Logger.log(f.getName())
}
```

Comment: What is the crucial difference from the code in the question that should make this work where that fails?

Comment: @greybeard ... I never worry about such things.  I just work until I get the code working and then I stop.